# Difference between propositionals True/False and booleans true/false in Coq

Tags: coq

The definition for the booleans `true`/`false` and their link with the propositional types `True`/`False` is described in [Coq.Bool.Bool](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Bool.Bool.html) :

```
Inductive bool : Set := true : bool | false : bool

Definition Is_true (b:bool) :=
  match b with
    | true => True
    | false => False
  end.
```

When it comes to the `bool` type, I more or less understand their purpose and function, but that is not the case for the `Prop` types. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028360/redundant-clause-in-match) gives a good example of my confusion. As presented there, the following is not a valid definition:

> ```
> Definition inv (a: Prop): Prop :=
> match a with
> | False => True
> | True => False
> end.
> ```

Resulting in "`Pattern "True" is redundant in this clause.`". The same definition with `bool` types on the other hand, compiles fine:

```
Definition inv (a: bool): bool :=
  match a with
  | false => true
  | true => false
  end.
```

[Ptival's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27029361/14656198) explains well why this happens in the pattern-matching sense: *"`False` is not a data constructor [...]"*. Indeed, that is clear by examining `True` and `False`:

```
Print True.
Print False.
```

```
Inductive True : Prop :=  I : True
Inductive False : Prop :=
```

In that case however, my question becomes: why? If they are not the same as `true`/`false`, then what are they? Specifically:

- What is the purpose of creating the booleans `true` and `false` from the propositional `True` and `False`, instead of merging them into one primitive construct?
- If the `Prop` versions `True`/`False` don't mean the same as the `bool` versions `true`/`false`, then what do they actually mean and what are the they supposed to represent in contrast with their boolean variants?

Comment: This question might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31554453/1633770. It motivates the differences between bool and Prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer the different questions that you have.
To begin with, in the pattern-matching

```
Definition inv (a: Prop): Prop :=
  match a with
  | False => True
  | True => False
  end.
```

Coq tells you it's redundant because it interprets `False` and `True` as variables that will be bound. Indeed `True` and `False` can't be matched against so it assumes you mean to name your variable `True` or `False`.
This code is equivalent to

```
Definition inv (a: Prop): Prop :=
  match a with
  | x => True
  | y => False
  end.
```

Then you can see why `y` would be redundant: you are saying match any value to `True` and any value to `False`.

---

The greatest confusion you have I think is thinking that `True` and `False` should somehow mean the same as `true` and `false`. The short answer is: there is no relation at all, except in the name.

Actually `True` and `False` are closer to `bool` than they are to `true` and `false`: they are (data) types.
`True` is the type containing only one element, and `False` is the empty type, with no inhabitant.

```
Inductive True : Prop :=
| I : True.

Inductive False : Prop :=.
```

(Admittedly, the definition of `False` can be a bit weird, but it really says that it's a type which has no constructor.)

By contrast, `bool` is a type with two elements: `true` and `false`.
So you can have `h : True` which is a proof of `True` but not `x : true` because `true` is not a type, its rather a piece of data.

Data can be observed (pattern-matching) but not data types.

I really want to insist that `true` and `false` are not *variants* of `True` and `False`. `true` and `false` are just bits and don't really have any meaning besides how you use them. `True` and `False` on the other hand have very precise meaning. `True` is the trivial proposition that is always provable, and `False` is the proposition that is never provable, having `h : False` expresses a contradiction.

The elimination principle of `False` shows how you can use it:

```
False_rect : ∀ P : Type, False → P
```

It says that you can derive *anything* from a proof of `False`.